# Issue reading from a text file

Tags: c++

There is a text file containing two columns of numbers such as:

```
4014 4017
4014 4021
4014 4023
4014 4030
4014 4037
4014 4038
4016 4025
4017 4021
4017 4026
4017 4030
4018 4023
4018 4030
```

and a C++ program reading the file using this code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7868998)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

int main() {
list<int> v_list, u_list, v_unique_sorted_list;
ifstream infile("text.txt");

int v, u;

while (infile >> v >> u)
{
    v_list.insert(v_list.end(), v);
    u_list.insert(u_list.end(), u);

    cout << v << " " << u << endl;
}
```

I'm using CLion and the output on the run console is:

```
3880 3908
38803982 3994
3982 399

3824 3902
38243873 3943
3873 3948

3986 4033
3987 40124016 4025
4017 4021
```

This is part of the output. The actuall output is very big. Why is my reading scrambled??

Comment: Check txt file coding: Is UNICODE, or ANSI and change that to ANSI.

Comment: Because your input file is scrambled.

Comment: output of your code is perfectly ok in my machine.

Comment: @ProsenGhosh Could you please check the actual file. It's this one https://snap.stanford.edu/data/facebook_combined.txt.gz

Comment: @SamVarshavchik the link to my file is this https://snap.stanford.edu/data/facebook_combined.txt.gz it doesn't seem scrambled.

Comment: @neiiic The encoding is UTF-8.

Comment: @Ctrlfreak Change that to ansi. And tell its better.

Comment: here is your output file. http://paste.ubuntu.com/15090517/

Comment: @ProsenGhosh So, in you computer it runs fine?

Comment: yes, in my computer it run fine.

Comment: @ProsenGhosh Thank you I'll try on linux also.

Comment: and the file character encoding is UTF-8 ,so the encoding is not a problem.

Comment: The output looks to me as if two threads or processes are running at the same time and writing to the same output.

Comment: It's because you're not consuming the newlines.

Comment: Just tested this code on Debian and it works without the issues found on windows.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that there's a newline on all of the lines of your input file (except for the last line, of course).

For this reason, I tend to use `std::getline` instead of just extracting the data directly. This should work for you:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    std::list<int> v_list, u_list, v_unique_sorted_list;

    std::ifstream fin("text.txt");
    std::string line;

    // while we can get data from the input file
    while(std::getline(fin, line)) {
        // put the line in a stream
        std::stringstream ss(line); 
        int v, u;

        // extract two ints from the stream
        ss >> v >> u;

        std::cout << v << " " << u << std::endl;

        v_list.insert(v_list.end(), v);
        u_list.insert(u_list.end(), u);
    }
}
```

Comment: This was the second example on the link I posted. It gave me the same results, although I will test it tomorrow to be sure.

Comment: Oops. I didn't see that link! This should definitely work, though. You're not consuming newlines.

Comment: There must be something wrong with your data (i.e., maybe there are carriage returns sprinkled in with newlines).